# vb.net XML For loop

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have code for reading XML elements like this:

```
Dim xmlRoot As XElement = XDocument.Load("x:\books.xml").Root

For Each book As XElement In xmlRoot.<book>
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<title>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<author>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<year>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<price>.Value)
Next
```

What I want now is, how to display only 10 elements. Now I have displayed all xml elements but I need only first 10.
Tried with few For loop combinations but didn't get it work.

Thanks

Comment: what combinations have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this - notice `Take(10)` at the end:

```
For Each book As XElement In xmlRoot.<book>.Take(10)
```

[Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method on IEnumerable, you can use it with anything, not just XElements.

Comment: Perfect! Thank You! Didn't know about the "Take" extension. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own indicator to your existing `For`.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0 'No loops yet
For Each book As XElement In xmlRoot.<book>
    Debug.WriteLine(book.<title>.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(book.<author>.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(book.<year>.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(book.<price>.Value)

    i = i + 1 'Completed one more loop
    If (i = 10) Then Exit For 'Completed 10 loops, so stop
Next
```